# is there anyway to handle EOFError with sys.stdio.readline() instead of input() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input())
        print(n)
    except EOFError:
        break
```

I change the code above bit, to make it faster. like down below

```
import sys
while True:
    try:
        n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
        print(n)
    except EOFError:
        break
```

but I realized that sys.stdin.readline() doesn't make EOFError after I ran it.
than input() is the only way to run the loop that I wrote?
or is there any way faster than input

Comment: stdin may be a file or it may be something else like a terminal. If it is a terminal, it won't EOF.

Comment: Related, maybe even a duplicate: [What is the perfect counterpart in Python for "while not EOF"](/q/15599639/4518341)

Comment: that loop was kind a chuck for checking the number that i enter it. so i just want to shorten the running time

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns an empty line as `''`, and signals the end of the input with an `EOFError`.

`readline` returns an empty line as `'\n'` and signals the end of the input with `''`.

In other words, `input` raises an exception because it alway strips the trailing end-of-line character and needs some way to distinguish between an empty line and no line.

For your code, you need to check the return value of `sys.stdin.readline` before you attempt to parse it as an `int`.

```
import sys


while (line := sys.stdin.readline()):
    n = int(line)
```

If `readline` returns an empty string, the loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.stdin` is a file object, so you could simply loop over it:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    n = int(line)
    print(n)
```